# How to check the uuid of a virtualbox vdi?

Tags: virtualbox, uuid, vdi, vmdk

How can I check the `uuid` of a `vdi` or `vmdk`?

There should be some command line on `VBoxManage` to show it.

I know I read it some place in the docs, but now for some reason I can't find it...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Run `VBoxManage` and pass it [`showhdinfo`](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#id423646) and your VDI:

```
VBoxManage.exe showhdinfo "c:\MyMachine.vdi"
```

Comment: For the record, I learned today this will also register the VDI if it wasn't already registered.  This was great as I had just rebuilt my host machine after a crash and had to setup virtualbox all over again. I couldn't figure out how to register them, so I used this command to get the UUID so I could find the right VDI that I was missing and as a by product it registered it for me!

Comment: shows "cannot get format..." probably corrupted. any clue about how can this be recovered?

Answer (score 41):

`VBoxManage list vms` will list the virtual machines and their uuids without having to know the path to the particular vdi.

Comment: VBoxManage list hdds its better in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can open `C:\Users\username\.VirtualBox\VirtualBox.xml` for `.vbox` files:

```xml
<VirtualBox>
  <Global>
    <MachineRegistry>
      <MachineEntry uuid="{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}" src="C:/mybox.vbox"/>
    </MachineRegistry>
  </Global>
</VirtualBox>
```