# Resizing disk space on vagrant box

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I'd like to give my box some more disk space. I'm trying to do this through the vagrantfile as follows:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
    # ..
    config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]
    config.vm.customize ["modifyhd", :id, "--resize", 4096]
end
```

This gives me the error:

```
A customization command failed:
["modifyhd", "e87d8786-88be-4805-9c2a-45e88b8e0e56", "--resize", "4096"]

The following error was experienced:

VBoxManage: error: The given path 'e87d8786-88be-4805-9c2a-45e88b8e0e56' is not fully qualified
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Medium, interface IMedium, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "OpenMedium(Bstr(pszFilenameOrUuid).raw(), enmDevType, enmAccessMode, fForceNewUuidOnOpen, pMedium.asOutParam())" at line 178 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp


Please fix this customization and try again.
```

I'm trying to piece the information together from http://docs.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/customize.html
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: I would argue that it is on topic because the customization script is a program written in Ruby and has to do with setting up a dev environment which is essentially a programming topic. But - feel free to place this question wherever you like :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending modifyhd the UUID of the VM (provided by vagrant) while it expects the UUID of the VDI.
You will need to use the absolute path to the actual VDI file or its UUID. You can use the following command to get the UUID of the VDI: `VBoxManage showhdinfo <filename>` (see [virtualbox - how to check what is the uuid of a vdi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379799/virtualbox-how-to-check-what-is-the-uuid-of-a-vdi))

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way to do this from within the vagrant file.

Comment: "The special value :id, when found in the array, is replaced with the actual UUID of the virtual machine that Vagrant is creating.". Wouldn't that indicate it's passing the UUID of the VDI?

Comment: I think the actual problem is the disk format is VMDK, not VDI. VMDK is not support by --resize

Comment: What is the filename? -nevermind, I found it using locate *.vdi (It's at ~/VirtualBox VMs/Linux Mint/Snapshots/{UUID}.vdi )

Answer (score 3):

I created a new disk, added and extended the older.

My Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
config.vm.box = "bseller/oracle-standard"
config.vm.define :oracle do |oracle| 
  oracle.vm.hostname = 'oraclebox'
  oracle.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", owner: "oracle", group: "oinstall" 
  oracle.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.33.13'
  oracle.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 1521, host: 1521
  oracle.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "oraclebox"]
     if !File.exist?("disk/oracle.vdi")
       vb.customize [
            'createhd', 
            '--filename', 'disk/oracle', 
            '--format', 'VDI', 
            '--size', 60200
            ] 
       vb.customize [
            'storageattach', :id, 
            '--storagectl', "SATA", 
            '--port', 1, '--device', 0, 
            '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', 'disk/oracle.vdi'
            ]
     end     
  end
  oracle.vm.provision "shell", path: "shell/add-oracle-disk.sh"
  oracle.vm.provision "shell", path: "shell/provision.sh"
end
end
```

This will create new disk in

```
disk
    |-- oracle.vdi
shell
    |-- provision.sh
Vagrantfile
```

and add in your box. The new disk is of 60GB
My shell `provision.sh`

```
set -e
set -x

if [ -f /etc/disk_added_date ] ; then
   echo "disk already added so exiting."
   exit 0
fi

sudo fdisk -u /dev/sdb <<EOF
n
p
1


t
8e
w
EOF

sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb1
sudo vgextend VolGroup /dev/sdb1
sudo lvextend -L50GB /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
sudo resize2fs /dev/VolGroup/lv_root
date > /etc/disk_added_date
```

This script was adapted from [SHC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317338/how-can-i-increase-disk-size-on-a-vagrant-vm) to box [bseller/oracle-standard](https://vagrantcloud.com/bseller/boxes/oracle-standard). For full code, see my project [oraclebox](https://github.com/acfreitas/oraclebox) in GitHub

Comment: Hi @acfreitas

I'm following your project in GitHub and tried to include the code for setting VM Storage on my Vagrant File, but I got some error. 
Please help and see my posted question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642768/error-setting-vm-storage-size-in-vagrant

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking at this, and I haven't found any way to actually do this directly. However, you can achieve the effect using [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) as a provisioner. First of all, it is definitely possible with Vagrant to create and add a second disk, which you can then add and mount any way you like using Ansible.

However, Ansible also has the ability to run local commands (on the host). This is with Ansible's `local_action` feature. I used it [here](https://github.com/capsid/capsid-vagrant/blob/fa04993b5bb3cea8ea1c8ef608d09eec366c5769/roles/kernel/tasks/main.yml) to reboot a Vagrant VM after a kernel upgrade and tell the host to wait until it has restarted, but you could use this with the command or shell actions to find the HD identifier, shutdown the VM, and configure the hard disk, then reboot. At least in theory.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question is old but I saw no answer accepted.

`The given path 'e87d8786-88be-4805-9c2a-45e88b8e0e56' is not fully qualified`  shows up because the UUID `e87d8...` is VirtualBox vm UUID, not your SATA storage disk device UUID. You an find the storage device UUID by `VBoxManage showvminfo e87d8786-88be-4805-9c2a-45e88b8e0e56|grep vdi`. The replace `:id` with the SATA storage UUID in Vagrantfile modifyhd line.

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK... Solved...

VBoxManage.exe wan't in my path so what I did was go to (you have to go to that path):

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

then used the command:

VBoxManage.exe modifyhd "C:\Users\MyUser\VirtualBox VMs\MachineName\HDName.vdi " --resize 20480

For 20 GB size a HD

This DON'T work: 
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd "C:\Users\MyUser\VirtualBox VMs\MachineName\HDName.vdi " --resize 20480

You have to be in the path: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

You can add new disk instead.
First use virtual box GUI to add another 
virtual disk

[image]

then use fdisk to create a primary disk partion

```
root@linux-dev:/# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 9.9 GiB, 10632560640 bytes, 20766720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x83312a2b

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 19816447 19814400  9.5G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       19818494 20764671   946178  462M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       19818496 20764671   946176  462M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

root@linux-dev:/# fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x5eb328b9.

Command (m for help): m

Help:

  DOS (MBR)
   a   toggle a bootable flag
   b   edit nested BSD disklabel
   c   toggle the dos compatibility flag

  Generic
   d   delete a partition
   l   list known partition types
   n   add a new partition
   p   print the partition table
   t   change a partition type
   v   verify the partition table

  Misc
   m   print this menu
   u   change display/entry units
   x   extra functionality (experts only)

  Save & Exit
   w   write table to disk and exit
   q   quit without saving changes

  Create a new label
   g   create a new empty GPT partition table
   G   create a new empty SGI (IRIX) partition table
   o   create a new empty DOS partition table
   s   create a new empty Sun partition table

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5eb328b9


Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1):
First sector (2048-41943039, default 2048):
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-41943039, default 41943039):

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 20 GiB.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5eb328b9

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Make newly created disk partition a ext4 filesystem

```
root@linux-dev:/# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1 
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Creating filesystem with 5242624 4k blocks and 1310720 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 0301b56a-1d80-42de-9334-cc49e4eaf7b2
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Mount the disk partition to a directory

```
root@linux-dev:/# mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /home/chenchun
root@linux-dev:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.2G  3.3G  5.5G  38% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs            74M  4.4M   70M   6% /run
tmpfs           185M     0  185M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           185M     0  185M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            372G  240G  133G  65% /vagrant
/dev/sdb1        20G   44M   19G   1% /home/chenchun
```